# Transitioning to ARC causing delegate issues

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

After transitioning a project to ARC, I've been having some issues with delegate methods not being called/being called on deallocated instances.  I've realized that the problem is that I have a variable that gets allocated and then executes an asynchronous task. For a simple example, assume that there is an object called MyService that responds to a delegate method, executeDidSucceed:

```
- (void)fireRequest {
    MyService *service = [[MyService alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    [service execute];
}
```

The original code would look something like this:

```
- (void)fireRequest {
    MyService *service = [[[MyService alloc] initWithDelegate:self] autorelease];
    [service execute];
}
```

With ARC, I understand that a `release` call gets added after `[service execute]` gets called. And I also understand that because the method is asynchronous, the `service` object will get deallocated, and a call to the deallocated object will be made for the delegate method.

I know a solution would be to make `service` an instance variable and give it the `strong` property so we can retain ownership of it.  And I know of a solution where we could create a block and use a completion handler so the delegate stays retained until the block is completed.  My question is, what's the best way of handling a situation like this? Or more so, what's the "best practice" for resolving this while transitioning to ARC?

Comment: Are you able to use auto-zeroing weak references?

Comment: It's unclear from where the delegate method is being called. MyService would be getting deallocated even before, since it's autoreleased. The only difference between the old and the ARC version is autorelease vs release. I can't figure why one would call the delegate and one not - does the async method happen to be called before the old autorelease pool's drain? I think ultimately the answer here would be to use a strong property, nilled out by the delegate once called back.

Comment: Yeah, I believe the method does get called before the pool gets drained.

Comment: The question and answer is simply this: What would you like your object ownership graph to look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to make your Myservice object a member to this class. ARC is cleaning it up as soon as this function completes because you no longer have a reference to it.

It's also my opinion that its a good practice to do since you don't have a reference to that object until it calls a delegate (if it does) and depending on the situation you may need stop the service before it completes.