# ARC - Delegate (assign) is released too early

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

We are subclassing `UITabBarController` as well as `UITabBarControllerDelegate` to handle certain events concerning tab switches.

Now in our custom tab bar controller we have:

```
- (id)initCustomTabBarController {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
       [self setDelegate:[[CustomTabBarControllerDelegate alloc] init]];
       // ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Since we transitioned the project to ARC, the delegate is released to early which causes a tab switch run into a deallocated instance.

The property is defined as `assign` in `UITabBarController.h` - which I obviously have no influence on.

What can I do to make the delegate object "live" longer than for the init method?

Comment: When did you release it before ARC?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786748/transitioning-to-arc-causing-delegate-issues?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have done it, it is expected that the delegate will not outlive the object, because it is weak. Remember, you created the object, it's up to you to hold on to it.

However - the pattern that you are using is incorrect.

The point of a delegate, is that it provides method implementations to a class that a class can't add for itself, because it doesn't have enough information. For example, a table view delegate. A table view, in order to be generic, cannot know how many rows or sections to display, so it asks it's delegate to supply this information.

In your case, you have an object that is creating it's own delegate. In which case, why bother having a delegate at all? Just implement the methods in the class.

Comment: The methods are in a different class because we have one tab bar controller subclass for each iPhone and iPad.

Comment: I was wrong, it's actually only used in one class, I implemented the delegate methods in the same class now - thanks for pointing out the wrong architecture!

Answer (score 2):

Yes this would be normal under ARC, since no reference to it is made (aka strong propteries) it should be released at the end of cycle.

Just make a property in the class where you assign the `CustomTabBarControllerDelegate` take make it strong. Then assign this property to the delegate.

In non ARC the way you have set it up you could have create a memory leak.